# apt wants to free my whole disk space

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I was trying to install viber using .deb package :

`dpkg --install viber.deb`

and got the following error :

```
Selecting previously unselected package viber.
(Reading database ... 373332 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack viber.deb ...
Unpacking viber (12.0.0.7) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of viber:
 viber depends on libssl1.0.0; however:
  Package libssl1.0.0:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package viber (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+18.04.20180207.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 viber
```

Since then I haven't been able to do anything using apt. I always get:

```
sudo apt install viber
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
viber is already the newest version (12.0.0.7).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 viber : Depends: libssl1.0.0 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The problem is, when I try:

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  viber
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 346 GB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Is it normal that it says my whole disk space is going to be freed? Otherwise what should I do to fix this?

Comment: Where did you get the package from?

Comment: And which version of Ubuntu do you use?

Comment: You were right to read your output carefully and avoid destroying your system. Good job! `libssl1.0.0` was dropped in favor of a newer version  (`libssl1.1`) after Ubuntu 18.04. Be sure to tell Viber that their package is old and stale. If you have `libssl1.1` already installed (most folks do), then try `sudo apt install --force-depends /path/to/viber.deb`. Alternately, viber seems available as a snap (`snap search viber`)

Comment: " Otherwise what should I do to fix this ?" find a newer version of the software. In other words: find a version intended for the Ubuntu release you use. Never a good idea to install software outside of the timeframe of an LTS.

Comment: @vidarlo From viber official website

Comment: @mook765 I use ubuntu 19.04

Comment: @user535733 the --force-depends argument doesn't seem to exist it says "Command line option --force-depends is not understood in combination with the other options"

Comment: Oops, sorry: apt/dpkg confusion. Try: `sudo dpkg --install --ignore-depends /path/to/viber.deb` The `--ignore-depends` flag converts fatal errors into mere warnings. There is no guarantee the software will work with the newer libssl, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks i have installed viber using `dpkg --force-all -i viber.deb`  but i still have a problem with apt, for example i cannot run apt autoremove it still says that I have unmet dependencies, is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: No. That's the problem with using --force flags.

Comment: @user535733 what do you mean ? is there a way to get apt back working because i cannot install anything in this situation, maybe if i could remove viber manually ?

Comment: Correct - apt was trying to tell you that the viber deb was *incompatible* with your release of Ubuntu. That's why you needed to --force it. Uninstall the deb, and that will fix your system. Like I said, viber needs to know that their deb is obsolete. And looks like unofficial snaps are available that won't break your system.

Comment: @Walid 19.04 is End of life, after fixing your problem you should upgrade to a supported release.

Comment: @user535733 ah okay i got it now, thank you so much